The use of "if" in definitions of monotonic and lexicographic preferences
[EDIT: In light of useful comments I have updated the question substantially
Let $N=\{1,..., 3\}$ be a set of goods. Consider the following two definitions:
Definition P. A preference relation $\succeq$ on $\mathbb{R}_{++}^3$ is monotonic if $x\succeq y$ if $x_i\geq y_i$ for all $i\in N$.
Definition Q. A monotonic preference $\succeq$ on $\mathbb{R}_{++}^3$ is defined as $x\succeq y$ if $x_i\geq y_i$ for all $i\in N$.
Are Definition P and Definition Q equivalent? The reason I am asking: in Definition P it is clear that the first "if" should be read as "if and only if" whereas the second "if" should be read as just "if". In Definition Q, there is only one "if", should it be read as "if and only if" or should it be read just as "if"? If the former is true Definition P and Q are not equivalent, if the latter is true then they are equivalent.

For reference, the old version of the question is stated below (can be if ignored)
Consider:
Definition 1. A weakly monotonic preference relation $\succeq$ on $\mathbb{R}_{++}^3$ is defined as $x\succ y$ if $x_i>y_i$ for all $i\in N$.
Definition 2. The lexicographic preference relation $\succeq$ on $\mathbb{R}_{++}^3$ is defined as $x\succeq y$ if $x_1>y_1$ or $x_1=y_1$ and $x_2\geq y_2$.
When placed after the concept that is defined "if" means "if and only if" in definitions. In the definitions above, it is more tricky. Definition 1 only makes sense when "if" is read as an "if", whereas Definition 2 only makes sense when "if" is read as an "if and only if".

For a generic statement like the one above, how should one interpret the "if"?
In other words, which of the definitions above is phrased incorrectly?


Did you want the bottom part of the equals sign in definition 1?

Why do you think Definition 1 makes sense only when “if” is read as “if”?

@Greg Martin: The reason that Definition 1 only makes sense when "if" is read as "if" is that this is what weak monotonicity means: a preference is weakly monotonic whenever it always strictly prefer bundles that have strictly more of all goods.

@JonathanZ: Not sure I understand the question. I want the inequality to be strict in Definition 1.

@Gurkan You didn't answer Greg Martin's question. You stated that "Definition 1 only makes sense when "if" is read as an "if". I (and I assume Greg Martin as well) think Definition 1 one makes perfect sense when read as "if and only if". Apparently you don't think so, so it would be interesting in which cases you think the "only if" part is violated. Mathematically that would mean you should give us 2 triples $x=(x_1, x_2, x_3), y=(y_1, y_2, y_3)$ where $x$ is weakly monotonically preferred to $y$ but $x_i>y_i$ is not true for all $i \in {1,2,3}$.

@Ingix Thanks, I'll try to answer more comprehensively.
Suppose that $x\succeq y$ iff $\sum_{i\in N} x_i \geq \sum_{i\in N} y_i$ (i.e., goods are perfect substitutes). As Weak Monotonicity is typically conceived, these preferences satisfy Weak Monotonicity. However, here it is clearly not the case that $x\succ y$ only if $x_i>y_i$ for all $i\in N$ (for example, $x=(2, 2, 1)\succ y=(1, 1, 2)$ even if $y_3=2>x_3=1$). Hence, Definition 1 only makes sense as a definition of Weak Monotonicity when "if" is interpreted as "if" and not as "if and only if". Does that help?

You've used the "$\succeq$" symbol in your statement of definition 1.

Yes, the intended meaning is that the set of weakly monotonic preference relations is ${\succeq: x\succ y \text{ if } x_i>y_i \text{ for all } i\in N}$, where (as is standard) $\succ$ is defined so that for all $x, y\in \mathbb{R}_{++}^3$, $x\succ y$ iff $x \succeq y$ and not $y\succeq x$.

Short answer: by convention, in definitions, “if” always means “if and only if”. A written definition that doesn't abide by that definition is destined to be confusing or misleading or just plain wrong.
Longer answer: I attempt to clarify the question being asked (in light of the comments). The OP seems to be thinking about the following non-strict partial order on ordered triples (although the $3$ plays no special role):
Definition A. For $x,y\in\Bbb R^3$, we say that $x\succeq y$ if $x_i\ge y_i$ for all $1\le i\le 3$.
The OP then seems to want to define a strict (nonreflexive) version of this nonstrict (reflexive) relation as follows:
Definition B. We say that $x\succ y$ if $x\succeq y$ and $y\not\succeq x$.
Great (although I think it would be clearer to say “$x\succeq y$ and $x\ne y$”, but they are provably equivalent).
The OP then asks about the following “definition”:
Definition 1. We say that $x\succ y$ if $x_i>y_i$ for all $1\le i\le 3$.
In a vacuum this is a perfectly good definition of a nonreflexive transitive partial order. However, if the OP considers Definition B to be the true definition of $\succ$, then Definition 1 is not a valid definition of $\succ$, precisely because “if” in a definition always means “if and only if”.
If somebody wanted to point out a relationship between this new relation and Definition B, it would be appropriate to have a Lemma or something that said “If $x_i>y_i$ for all $1\le i\le 3$, then $x\succ y$.” That is a valid way of indicating an implication that is not an equivalence.

Thanks! I appreciate you taking the time to engage with this. I think the focus on $\succ$ vs $\succeq$ is not really central to the question I am asking. I have tried to clarify the question to focus on the central point: in definitions that are stated in a somewhat nonstandard way, how should the "if" be interpreted? Hope the new version of the question helps precisifying what I had in mind. Sorry for not being sufficiently clear earlier.

In both definitions, changing the final “if” to ”whenever” would make things much clearer.

Here's the deal: Definitions (of properties objects might have, say) all have this form: “An object $X$ is adjective if (some math statement is true about $X$).” In definitions, by convention, the “if” that we see explicitly always means “if and only if”. After that, the “some math statement” is read like any other math statement outside a definition, and in particular “if” means “if” within it. If the overall definition is written in such a way that it's unclear what “some math statement” is saying, then the definition should be written in a different way to make the meaning more clear.

One point is that a definition is not really a mathematical statement with a true-or-false value. Rather, a definition is giving a mathematical meaning to a word or phrase or piece of notation, which becomes a shorthand for that longer meaning. Giving a meaning to a symbol is always an equivalence: we say what things the symbol means, and everyone understands that the symbol doesn't also mean some other secret things. Once the definition has been given, saying that the definition equals its meaning is an if-and-only-if statement. But the act of making a definition isn't really logic at all.

Thanks, that all makes sense. I think my takeaway from what you wrote is that definitions like "Definition Q" are phrased in a somewhat ambiguous way, and that it is preferable to phrase them like "Definition P".

Definition P would be even clearer if the second “if” was replaced by “whenever”. And if “monotonic” were put in italics or otherwise emphasized, to show what word we are defining. And if $\Bbb R_{++}^3$$ were defined.
